# Customizable mail server - what are my options?

Tags: java, python, ruby, email, clojure

I am interested to build a mail service that allows you to incorporate custom logic in the your mail server.

For example, user A can reply to helloworld@mysite.com once and subsequent emails from user A to helloworld@mysite.com will not go through until certain actions are taken.

I am looking for something simple and customizable, preferably open-sourced. I am fluent in most modern languages.

What email servers do you guys recommend for this?

Comment: As there are *many* options available this question can't really be answered (it's basically a poll.)  (Best to ask in chat).  My vote is for [`lamson`](http://lamsonproject.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Almost every mail server has some form of extensibility where you can insert logic in the mail-flow process, it's how some spam filters were implemented before they were built directly in to the servers. Personally, I use Exchange server which has a variety of points and APIs to extend it, such as SMTP Sinks.

However, this question is off-topic and shouldn't be on StackOverflow.

I suggest you build your own server - implementing a server-side version of SMTP and IMAP can be done by a single person, or use an existing library, it shouldn't take you more than a year if you put in a couple of hours each day.

Comment: +1 "it shouldn't take you more than a year if you put in a couple of hours each day". Don't forget adding a suitably obtuse and hard to understand macro language, such as sendmail's .conf files.